# Passing/Accessing props in stateless child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, stateless

I know you can pass all a react components props to it's child component like this:

```
const ParentComponent = () => (
   <div>
     <h1>Parent Component</h1>
     <ChildComponent {...this.props} />
   </div>
)
```

But how do you then retrieve those props if the child component is stateless? I know if it is a class component you can just access them as `this.prop.whatever`, but what do you pass as the argument into the stateless component?

```
const ChildComponent = ({ *what goes here?* }) => (
   <div>
      <h1>Child Component</h1>
   </div>
)
```

Comment: Are you working with a functional component or class component?

Comment: Yes - my setup is as I have stated in the original post

Answer (score 20):

When you write

```
const ChildComponent = ({ someProp }) => (
   <div>
      <h1>Child Component {someProp}</h1>
   </div>
)
```

From all the props that you are passing to the `childComponent` you are just destructuring to get only `someProp`. If the number of props that you want to use in ChildComponents are countable(few) amongst the total number of props that are available, destructuring is a good option as it provides better readability.

Suppose you want to access all the props in the child component then you need not use `{}` around the argument and then you can use it like `props.someProp`

```
const ChildComponent = (props) => (
   <div>
      <h1>Child Component {props.someProp}</h1>
   </div>
)
```

Answer (score 11):

Are you looking for the ES6 named argument syntax (which is merely destructuring) ?

```
const ChildComponent = ({ propName }) => (
    <div>
     <h1>Child Component</h1>
 </div>
)

const ChildComponent = (props) => ( // without named arguments
    <div>
     <h1>Child Component</h1>
 </div>
)
```

Optionally there is a second argument to your function depending of whether you specified a *context* for your component or not.

Perhaps it would be more helpful wityh a links to the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/components-and-props.html). As stated in the first article about *functional components*. Whatever props passed on to the component is represented as an object passed as first argument to your functional component.

To go a little further, about the spread notation within jsx.

When you write in a component :

```
<Child prop1={value1} prop2={value2} />
```

What your component will receive is an plain object which looks like this :

```
{ prop1: value1, prop2: value2 }
```

(Note that it's not a Map, but an object with only strings as keys).

So when you're using the *spread* syntax with a JS object it is effectively a shortcut to this

```
const object = { key1: value1, key2: value2 }
<Component {...object}/>
```

Is equivalent to

```
<Component key1={value1} key2={value2} />
```

And actually compiles to

```
return React.createElement(Component, object); // second arg is props
```

And you can of course have the second syntax, but be careful of the order. The more specific syntax (prop=value) must come last : the more specific instruction comes last.

If you do :

```
<Component key={value} {...props} />
```

It compiles to

```
React.createElement(Component, _extends({ key: value }, props));
```

If you do (what you probably should)

```
<Component {...props} key={value} />
```

It compiles to

```
React.createElement(Component, _extends(props, { key: value }));
```

Where extends is *Object.assign (or a polyfill if not present).

To go further I would really recommend taking some time to observe the output of Babel with their [online editor](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&code=function%20A%20(props)%20%7B%0A%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%3CComponent%20key%3D%7Bvalue%7D%20%7B...props%7D%20%2F%3E%0A%20%20%0A%7D). This is very interesting to understand how jsx works, and more generally how you can implement es6 syntax with ES5 tools.

Comment: Actually I'm trying to avoid listing all of the individual props in the parent component as it's verbose. So I want to use the `{...this.props}` syntax. I just don't know how to access these in the child component.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Spread Attributes reducing code bloat.  This comes in the form of `{'somearg':123, ...props}` or `{...this.props}`, with the former allowing you to set some fields, while the latter is a complete copy.  Here's an example with `ParentClass.js` :

```
import React from 'react';
import SomeComponent from '../components/SomeComponent.js';

export default class ParentClass extends React.Component {
    render() {
        <SomeComponent
            {...this.props}
        />
    }
}
```

If I do, `<ParentClass getCallBackFunc={() => this.getCallBackFunc()} />`, or if I do `<ParentClass date={todaysdatevar} />`, the props `getCallBackFunc` or `date` will be available to the `SomeComponent` class.  This saves me an incredible amount of typing and/or copying/pasting.

Source: [**ReactJS.org: JSX In Depth, Specifying the React Element Type, Spread Attributes**](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html).  Official POD:

> If you already have props as an object, and you want to pass it in JSX, you can use ... as a “spread” operator to pass the whole props object. These two components are equivalent:
>
> ````
>  return <Greeting firstName="Ben" lastName="Hector" />;
> }
>
> function App2() {
>  const props = {firstName: 'Ben', lastName: 'Hector'};
>  return <Greeting {...props} />;
> }```
> ````

Now, let's apply this to your code sample!

```
const ParentComponent = (props) => (
   <div>
     <h1>Parent Component</h1>
     <ChildComponent {...props} />
   </div>
);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
const ParentComponent = (props) => (
   <div>
     <h1>Parent Component</h1>
     <ChildComponent {...props} />
   </div>
);

const ChildComponent = ({prop1, ...rest}) =>{
  <div>
    <h1>Child Component with prop1={prop1}</h1>
    <GrandChildComponent {...rest} />
  </div>
}

const GrandChildComponent = ({prop2, prop3})=> {
  <div>
    <h1>Grand Child Component with prop2={prop1} and prop3={prop3}</h1>
  </div>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I thought I would add a simple ES2015, destructuring syntax I use to pass all props from a functional parent to a functional child component.

```
const ParentComponent = (props) => (
  <div>
    <ChildComponent {...props}/>
  </div>
);
```

Or if I have multiple objects (props of parent, plus anything else), I want passed to the child as props:

```
const ParentComponent = ({...props, ...objectToBeAddedToChildAsProps}) => (
  <div>
    <ChildComponent {...props}/>
  </div>
);
```

This destructuring syntax is similar to the above answers, but it is how I pass props along from functional components, and I think it is really clean. I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

> But how do you then retrieve those props if the child component is stateless?

```
const ChildComponent = ({ *what goes here?* }) => (
   <div>
      <h1>Child Component</h1>
   </div>
)
```

---

`ChildComponent` holds the name and the `props` will be the argument in the arrow function syntax just as you need:

```
 const ChildComponent = props => (
   <div>
     <p>{props.value ? props.value : "No value."}</p>
   </div>
 );
```

If you Babel-it it will create something like this:

```
 var ChildComponent = function ChildComponent(props) {
   return React.createElement(
     "div",
     null,
     React.createElement(
       "p",
       null,
       props.value ? props.value : "No value."
     )
   );
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, what seems to work for me is a variation on [Shubham's answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41813406/572747):

```
const ChildComponent = props => (
   <div>
      <h1>Child Component {props[0].someProp}</h1>
   </div>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using this

```
const ParentComponent = ({ prop1, prop2, prop3 }) => (
   <div>
     <h1>Parent Component</h1>
     <ChildComponent {...{ prop1, prop2, prop3 }} />
   </div>
);

const ChildComponent = ({ prop1, prop2, prop3 }) =>{
  <div>
    <h1>Child Component with prop1={prop1}</h1>
    <h1>Child Component with prop2={prop2}</h1>
    <h1>Child Component with prop2={prop3}</h1>
  </div>
}
```

Comment: I am seeing "prop1, prop2, prop3" recur several times here.  I think the idea is to have that effect without actually copying/pasting argument lists each time.